# Insurance quote - Report Moving Violation

Tags: united-states, california, car-insurance

I am trying to get renters' insurance and move car insurance all to the same company for a multi-line discount.

I live in CA, USA, and had a speeding ticket last year, but it was held confidential because I completed traffic school.  The state doesn't require reporting it to insurance.

Am I required to disclose this when getting a quote or policy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I unfortunately was in a similar situation (that was my first and only ticket ever), and when I asked for quote I told the agent that this was a "traffic school" ticket - it didn't affect my rate. That was with AAA insurance. This kind of ticket is considered "confidential" and is not reported to the insurance agencies, and they only count into the formula the convictions officially reported by the DMV.